# HTML Scrollbar only showing part of the box borders

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to integrate a scroll bar in the following `div` of my HTML template, and want the "box" to always show, even when empty. But when I do `overflow: scroll`, only part of the box borders appear (on the right and bottom side, but not on the top and left side). How can I fix this?

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <h1>Results</h1>
  <br><br>
  <div style="width: 500px; overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">
  <br>
  <p class="my-results"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a `border` style property as well. The `overflow: scroll` has nothing to do with top and left borders.

```
<div style="width: 500px; overflow: scroll; height: 400px; border: solid 1px #ccc">
   ...
</div>
```